# How to create RSpec tests for the following code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I need to create RSpec testing for the following ruby code and seem to run into issues every time I try. I would love an example or two of RSpec tests that could be created for the following code/methods which are in my controller:

```
  def edit
    @movie = Movie.find params[:id]
  end
   def update
    @movie = Movie.find params[:id]
    @movie.update_attributes!(movie_params)
    flash[:notice] = "#{@movie.title} was successfully updated."
    redirect_to movie_path(@movie)
  end
   def destroy
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
    @movie.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Movie '#{@movie.title}' deleted."
    redirect_to movies_path
  end
   def find_with_same_director
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
    @movies, check_info = Movie.find_with_same_director(params[:id])
    if check_info
      flash[:notice] = "'#{@movie.title}' has no director info"
      redirect_to movies_path
    end
  end
```

I have this so far:

```
RSpec.describe MoviesController, type: :controller do
  it 'should get all movies in the database' do
      get :index
      expect(response).to render_template :index
      expect(assigns[:movies]).to eq(Movie.all)
  end
  describe 'find_with_same_director' do
    it 'should call the find_with_same_director model method' do
      expect(Movie).to receive(:find_with_same_director).with(no_args)
      get :find_with_same_director, id: movie.id
    end
  end
end
```

but it is not covering it correctly. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: i think the powers that be in the rails world are recommending that people do not do controller tests anymore, but employ request specs instead. what do you mean it is not "covering it correctly"?

Comment: Well this is for an assignment, so can't do much about that.. I mean I think my syntax for the tests are incorrect as they're returning failure even though they should be working.

Comment: It'd be more helpful if you can share the failure reason you're getting

Comment: Why are you expecting no args with `find_with_same_director`? In the controller you pass an argument there.

Comment: You're right, I modified it to with(params[:id]) cause thats what i pass in when i call the function @maxpleaner

Comment: so ... was that the failure?

Answer (score 0):

```
RSpec.describe MoviesController, type: :controller do
 it 'should get all movies in the database' do
    get :index
    expect(response).to render_template :index
    expect(assigns[:movies]).to eq(Movie.all)
 end

 it 'should update movie in the database' do
   Factory.girl.create(:movie)
   before_movie_count = Movie.count

   put :update, id: movie.id

   expect(assigns[:movies]).to eq(...) # whatever data is passed

   expect(Movie.count).to eq(before_ml_count)
   expect(flash[:snack_class]).to eq(:notice.to_s)
   expect(flash[:snack_message]).to ends_with('was successfully updated')
   expect(response).to have_http_status(:redirect)
 end

 it 'should delete movie in the database' do
    Factory.girl.create(:movie)
    before_movie_count = Movie.count

    delete :update, id: movie.id

    expect(Movie.count).to eq(before_ml_count - 1)
    expect(flash[:snack_class]).to eq(:notice.to_s)
    expect(flash[:snack_message]).to ends_with('deleted')
    expect(response).to have_http_status(:redirect)
 end

 describe 'find_with_same_director' do
   it 'should call the find_with_same_director model method' do
     expect(Movie).to receive(:find_with_same_director).with(no_args)
     get :find_with_same_director, id: movie.id
   end
 end
end


#### in factory movie.rb

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :movie do
    # assign data to movie attributes here.
  end
end
```